# Why is this mangled edit "community"?

Tags: discussion, editing, community

https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/123246/4

The title was changed from the OP's

> Is it rude to say "Thanks for asking"?

to

> Is it okay to ask“ Thank you for asking”

I was about to comment on the poor grammar in the title when I realized that it had been edited in a nearly malicious manner.  How could this happen, under the aegis of "community"?

Comment: 'Community' is just the label given for an accepted edit by an anonymous user (there's no rampant AI editing posts poorly). Others approved it since (I'm surprised too) they all thought it was better than the previous one. Thinking the edit is 'malicious' is presumptuous; it's just poor. I think your edit/the original is best.

Comment: That is peculiar. It's "Community" because it was suggested anonymously. How it was approved is as yet a mystery.

Comment: The record seems to show the suggested edit was edited and approved by a user with 3,717 reputation. That's enough rep for the "edit questions and answers" privilege. Wouldn't that mean the revised edit would get immediate approval?

Answer (score 2):

I took a look through the timeline. I believe what happened was that there was a suggested anonymous edit that was improved by a 2K+ user, so both the improvements and the suggestion were marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the linked Meta SE question explains well. [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

"Community" appears (as far as I know) in the following situations:

> 1. One of the reviewers has chosen the option to "Improve" your suggested edit. In that case, depending on whether the reviewer has
>      chosen to deem your suggested edit helpful, the Community user will
>      approve or reject your edit. (Meta SE answer. There is another case in the link)

2. When a spam or offensive question or answer posted by unregistered user is deleted by the system or votes as indicated in the linked answer, [What is the best term in (global) copywriting: "sticky tape", "tape", "scotch tape" or "sellotape"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208839/what-is-the-best-term-in-global-copywriting-sticky-tape-tape-scotch-ta/337734#337734)

> This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown
>   - you can see the revision history for details.
>
> locked by **Community** ♦ 9 hours ago
>
> deleted by **Community** ♦ 9
>   hours ago

3. When a duplicate which is suggested by a close-voter is accepted by an OP. For example,  ["I would like to know what your name is" instead of "I would like to know what is your name"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337867/i-would-like-to-know-what-your-name-is-instead-of-i-would-like-to-know-what-i) was close-voted as duplicate by only two users, but closed because the OP approved it. That's why it shows "marked as duplicate by FumbleFingers, Hot Licks, **Community♦** 1 hour ago".

The "Community" (which approved the edit) means the edit suggestion was re-edited by another user. The user [**Community**](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) seems to represent an unregistered user or those who don't have the right to close-vote a question, etc. as indicated in the link:

> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - **Own suggested edits from anonymous users**
> - Remove abandoned questions

Comment: I don't think your last sentence is correct. The original poster isn't necessarily the approver of the edit, just either a high rep person who 'hijacked' the edit, or the group of people who 'approved' the edit.

Comment: "The "community" means ..... an anonymous user not registered on ELU...."   What a strange use of the word community, especially for an English language site.  How can a non registered user be  part of the community?"  I won't lose sleep over this, but it is demmed peculiar.

Comment: @ab2 ELU is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts + editing site for anonymous users.

Comment: Another case where "communty" appears as an editor.  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338015/why-this-sentence-grammatically-incorrect